# wpf polyline data query

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to draw arrow of -> <- and up down arrows as the button image in wpf.

but i could not understand how this polyline is drawing images on button..

can anyone give me the polyline datas for all the arrows??

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Path` tag. Here is a simple up arrow:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 10 5 M 5 0 L 5 10"/>
```

The data syntax here is simple: M stands for MoveTo and L for LineTo.